# Node in swift not appearing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to put a node in my game on Swift, but it's not appearing. Please help!

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let levelLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
        levelLabelNode.text = "Level"
        levelLabelNode.fontSize = 30
        levelLabelNode.fontColor = SKColor.white
        levelLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.75)
        self.addChild(levelLabelNode)
```

[here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CYyP.jpg)

Comment: Your code looks correct, so there must be some other issue causing it to not appear. Can you post more of your scene code?

Comment: print what size is your scene and what size is your view and post that here. Scene size and a view size are not neccessarily the same so it may happen that your node is off screen. Also try adding before you present the scene (in your GameViewController) something like scene.size = view.bounds.size and see what happens.

Comment: updated the code @nathan

Comment: Is "Arial" a supported font?

Comment: @i_am_jorf It is...

Comment: click the link for the screen shot. it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the same code I also faced the same problem coz the font color is white its match with background color.if you have changed the font's color then you can able to see the label in the screen

```
let levelLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
        levelLabelNode.text = "Level"
        levelLabelNode.fontSize = 30
        levelLabelNode.fontColor = SKColor.green
        levelLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.75)
        self.addChild(levelLabelNode)
```

[image]