# Nodes not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm trying to get a Node in xcode to appear, but it doesnt... here's the code.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let levelLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
        levelLabelNode.text = "Level"
        levelLabelNode.fontSize = 30
        levelLabelNode.fontColor = SKColor.green
        levelLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height*0.75)
        self.addChild(levelLabelNode)
      }
}
```

Comment: is the didMoveToView function running? did you do a print statement in there to make sure the function was being called?

Comment: It is running, I just tested that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node in swift not appearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557068/node-in-swift-not-appearing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had me stuck for a while.  The coordinate system of the programme (assuming you are running from the default) has point (0, 0) at the centre of the screen.  `self.frame.size.width` refers to the entire width of the screen.  Therefore, positioning a node at `self.frame.size.width/2` would position a node at the rightmost edge of the screen.  If you want to position your node centred horizontally and 3/4 up the screen try:

```
levelLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/4)
```

Hope this helped!

Remember: The coordinate system starts with (0, 0) in the centre and `self.frame.size.width` is the entire width of the screen.